# persisting data using Hibernate annotation

Tags: hibernate

I am quite new to hibernate.

I have got the following tables:

**Contract**

ContractID (PK),
Other Columns

**Provider**
ProviderID (PK),
Other Columns

**ContractualAgreement**
ContractualAgreementID (PK),
ContractID (FK),
ProviderID (FK),
Other Columns

I am using the following hibernate annotations:

```
 **Contract.java**

    {

    private List<ContractualAgreement> contractualAgreements = new ArrayList<ContractualAgreement>();

    @OneToMany(cascade= { javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL },fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn (name="ContractID", updatable=false,insertable=false)
    public List<ContractualAgreement> getContractualAgreements() {
            return this.contractualAgreements;
        }
    }

 **Provider.java**
{
    private List<ContractualAgreement> contractualAgreements = new     ArrayList<ContractualAgreement>();

    @OneToMany(cascade= { javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL },fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn (name="ProviderID", updatable=false,insertable=false,nullable=false)
    public List<ContractualAgreement> getContractualAgreements() {
            return this.contractualAgreements;
        }
    }
}

 **ContractualAgreement.java**
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ContractualAgreementID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getContractualAgreementId() {
        return this.contractualAgreementId;
    }

    public void setContractualAgreementId(long contractualAgreementId) {
        this.contractualAgreementId = contractualAgreementId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ProviderID",updatable=false,insertable=false,nullable=false)
    public Provider getProvider() {
        return this.provider;
    }

    public void setProvider(Provider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ContractID",updatable=false,insertable=false,nullable=false)
    public Contract getContract() {
        return this.contract;
    }
}
```

I populate the data in following order:

1. contract object on contractualagreement object.
2. contractualagreements list on provider.

and I try to save the Provider using saveOrUpdate.

Now it does save the data in provider,contractualagreement table with proper providerid in contractualagreemtent table but it does not save the data in contract table.

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing many things wrong.

First; the contractual agreement table is just a join table. It doesn't have any other functional column, and is thus used to materialize the association between contract and provider. This table should thus

- have no ID
- have a composite PK containing the two FKs
- not be mapped as an entity

You should have a ManyToMany association between Contract and Provider. The ManyToMany association will be mapped using the ContractualAgreement table.

Other problems in your code:

- you mark everything as `insertable = false, updateable = false`. If nothing can be insertable or updatable, how would these columns be populated?
- a OneToMany bidirectional association should have the many side mapped with a JoinColumn. The other side should just say: "this association is already mapped on the other side", using `OneToMany(mappedBy = "thePropertyOnTheOtherSide")`.

All this is well described in the Hibernate reference manual. [Read it](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the contractualagreement table do have other columns that are linked to other tables as well as it's own columns.

Comment: Then map your bidirectional OneToMany correctly, as per the reference manual.